# How can I pass tree annotations in sap.m.Tree with SAPUI5 version 1.44.8?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to implement sap.m.Tree with SAPUI5 library v1.44.8. which doesn't support tree annotations by default like

```
hierarchyLevelFor : 'HierarchyLevel',hierarchyNodeFor : 'NodeID',hierarchyParentNodeFor : 'ParentNodeID',hierarchyDrillStateFor : 'DrillState'
```

v1.50 and above has inbuilt support for it as shown in [demo kit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TreeOData/code/View.view.xml) but I can not update the version on the server due to other apps'. dependency.

How can I implement the same with my existing UI version?

My code is as below

```
<Tree 
                    id="TreeList" select="onToggleOpenState" mode="SingleSelectMaster"
                     items="{path: '/',
                                parameters : {
                                    countMode: 'Inline',
                                    treeAnnotationProperties : {hierarchyLevelFor : 'HierarchyLevel',
                                hierarchyNodeFor : 'NodeID',
                                hierarchyParentNodeFor : 'ParentNodeID',
                                hierarchyDrillStateFor : 'DrillState'}
                                }
                 }">
                    <StandardTreeItem title="{Description}" />
                </Tree>
```

Comment: Time being, I have converted standard oData structure into the tree structure via JS.